# When debugging, the login and register page layout appears white without the original template settings

Tags: .net-4.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've been using the Ajax Toolkit and when my start page (the login page) loads, it appears white, without the original template settings. It is the same on other pages, like the register page, where the color set and layout have been removed.

Does it have anything to do with the Ajax toolkit?